# Is there a way to have a background image behind a stack panel or a grid on Silverlight/WP7?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Right now I use a StackPanel where I have a small image but I want to have another image behind this image centered. I don't mind if the image fills all of the StackPanel or the Grid. I can make it the right size required for this.

Is this possible?

Or does one need to draw the image on another image at runtime? If so, would this not be slow for a Windows Phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../MyImages/MyFile.png" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- other contents -->
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

We are using the background of the `Grid` to show an image behind the contents of the `StackPanel`.

Comment: Thanks I tried this in an image that's directly in the main root of the solution (same as MainPage.xaml) but it can't find the image when I set the source to "Background.png". Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry the error message is `property Source was not found in type ImageBrush`.

Comment: @JoanVenge Sorry; change `Source` to `ImageSource`

Comment: For the last version of Avalonia (at this time of writing, 0.7.0) use `Source` instead of `ImageSource`